# Using JQuery to create a forward button and a backward button to go through data by ID in a mysql database

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, counter

I wish for one button to go forward through data by ID from a Mysql database and another button to go backward through the same data using JQuery. I do not want to display the entire database at once.  I would like to display, item ID 1, and then click a forward button and then item ID 2 is displayed. If I want to go forward again, I can click the same button and Item number 3 is displayed. If I want to go backward, I can click the backward button and now item number 2 is displayed again.

Currently, It displays all the items at once and with each item duplicating 6 times, which is the number of columns in the database. This is because the variable station_dataP +=.  If I remove the += and put the = sign, it only displays the last ID of 7, all by itself which is what I would like to see but it does not cycle back and forth through them.

ID: 1
Station: Carmichael Rd.
Address: 54 Myers Rd.
Sales: undefined
Operator: Michael Sears
Top SKU: undefined

ID: 1
Station: Carmichael Rd.
Address: 54 Myers Rd.
Sales: undefined
Operator: Michael Sears
Top SKU: undefined

ID: 1
Station: Carmichael Rd.
Address: 54 Myers Rd.
Sales: undefined
Operator: Michael Sears
Top SKU: undefined

ID: 1
Station: Carmichael Rd.
Address: 54 Myers Rd.
Sales: undefined
Operator: Michael Sears
Top SKU: undefined

ID: 1
Station: Carmichael Rd.
Address: 54 Myers Rd.
Sales: undefined
Operator: Michael Sears
Top SKU: undefined

ID: 1
Station: Carmichael Rd.
Address: 54 Myers Rd.
Sales: undefined
Operator: Michael Sears
Top SKU: undefined

ID: 2
Station: Baillou Hill
Address: 564 Jackson Ave.
Sales: undefined
Operator: Marla Pikes
Top SKU: undefined

ID: 2
Station: Baillou Hill
Address: 564 Jackson Ave.
Sales: undefined
Operator: Marla Pikes
Top SKU: undefined

etc..

I am able to do this in vanilla Javascript but I am not able to do so in JQuery. I will display the Javascript code below:

```
      <HTML>
     <button type = "button" id="previous"><<<<</button>
     <button type = "button" id="next">>>>></button>
     <br/>
     <br/>
     <div id="storesNav"></div>
```

```
   <JQUERY> - DOES NOT WORK PROPERLY

  $(document).ready(() => {
  $('#previous').click(()=> {
  $.ajax({
   url:'http://localhost:5000/alldata',
   type:'GET',
   datatype:'json',
   success:(data) => {

   var station_dataP ='';

   $.each(data, function (key,value){
      for(var i in value){
        if(i > 0){
        i--;
        }

   station_dataP +='<li>ID: '+value.ID+'</li>' +
                      '<li>Station: '+value.Station+'</li>' +
                      '<li>Address: '+value.Address+'</li>' +
                      '<li>Sales: '+value.Monthly_CStore_Sales+'</li>' +
                      '<li>Operator: '+value.Operator+'</li>' +
                      '<li>Top SKU: '+value.Top_SKU+'</li>' +
                      '</<li>'+'<br/>'; */

    });
   }      

   $('#storesNav').append(station_dataP);

     }
   });
 });  


 //(4)
 $('#next').click(()=> {
  $.ajax({
   url:'http://localhost:5000/alldata',
   type:'GET',
   datatype:'json',
   success:(data) => {

      var station_dataP ='';

      $.each(data, function (key,value){
      for(var i in value){
        len = value.length;
        if(i < len - 1){
        i++;
        }
        station_dataP +='<li>ID: '+value.ID+'</li>' +
                      '<li>Station: '+value.Station+'</li>' +
                      '<li>Address: '+value.Address+'</li>' +
                      '<li>Sales: '+value.Monthly_CStore_Sales+'</li>' +
                      '<li>Operator: '+value.Operator+'</li>' +
                      '<li>Top SKU: '+value.Top_SKU+'</li>' +
                      '</<li>'+'<br/>'; */

    });
   }      

   $('#storesNav').append(station_dataP);

     }
   });
 });
```

```
       <JAVASCRIPT> IT WORKS HERE BUT NOT THE JQUERY CODE. 

       function previous(xhttp){
        //var xhttp;
        //xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var users = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        len = users.length
        if(i > 0){
        i--;
        }

        var usersText2 = '';


        usersText2 += 
       '<div class="prev">' +
       'ID: ' + users[i].id + '<br>' +
       'Name: ' + users[i].name + '<br>' +
       'Email: '+ users[i].email;

       document.getElementById("usersNav").innerHTML = usersText2;

       }
       function next(xhttp){

      //var xhttp;
      //xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var users = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
      len = users.length;
      if(i < len - 1){
      i++;
      }

      var usersText = '';
      usersText += 
       '<div class="next">' +
       'ID: ' + users[i].id + '<br>' +
       'Name: ' + users[i].name + '<br>' +
        'Email: '+ users[i].email;

       document.getElementById("usersNav").innerHTML = usersText;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The brace input is invalid
Also, there should be no jquery source in ajax other than the parameter

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('#previous').click(() => {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:5000/alldata',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: (data) => {

                var station_dataP = '';

                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    for (var i in value) {
                        if (i > 0) {
                            i--;
                        }

                        station_dataP += '<li>ID: ' + value.ID + '</li>' +
                            '<li>Station: ' + value.Station + '</li>' +
                            '<li>Address: ' + value.Address + '</li>' +
                            '<li>Sales: ' + value.Monthly_CStore_Sales + '</li>' +
                            '<li>Operator: ' + value.Operator + '</li>' +
                            '<li>Top SKU: ' + value.Top_SKU + '</li>' +
                            '</<li>' + '<br/>';

                    }
                });
                $('#storesNav').append(station_dataP);
            }
        })
    });

    //(4)
    $('#next').click(() => {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:5000/alldata',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: (data) => {

                var station_dataP = '';

                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    for (var i in value) {
                        var len = value.length;
                        if (i < len - 1) {
                            i++;
                        }
                        station_dataP += '<li>ID: ' + value.ID + '</li>' +
                            '<li>Station: ' + value.Station + '</li>' +
                            '<li>Address: ' + value.Address + '</li>' +
                            '<li>Sales: ' + value.Monthly_CStore_Sales + '</li>' +
                            '<li>Operator: ' + value.Operator + '</li>' +
                            '<li>Top SKU: ' + value.Top_SKU + '</li>' +
                            '</<li>' + '<br/>';
                    }
                });
                $('#storesNav').append(station_dataP);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @FizzYam......Thank you for your contribution, can you identify what changes were made please>.....

Comment: @flowover

$('#storesNav').append(station_dataP);

This source has been passed into the success callback function

Comment: @flowover * / in the JQUERY source remove

Comment: @flowover len => var len

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('#previous').click(() => {


      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/alldata',
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: (data) => {
          $.each(data, function (i) {

          });


          data[i]
          console.log(i);
          if (i > 0) {
            i--;
            var station_loop = '';
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data[i].Station));

            station_loop += '<li>ID: ' + JSON.stringify(data[i].ID) + '</li>' +
              '<li>Station: ' + JSON.stringify(data[i].Station) + '</li>' +
              '<li>Address: ' + JSON.stringify(data[i].Address) + '</li>' +
              '<li>Sales: ' + JSON.stringify(data[i].Monthly_CStore_Sales) + '</li>' +
              '<li>Operator: ' + JSON.stringify(data[i].Operator) + '</li>' +
              '<li>Top SKU: ' + JSON.stringify(data[i].Top_SKU) + '</li>' +
              '</<li>' + '<br/>';

            $('#storesNav').html(station_loop);
          }
        }
      })
    });
  });

  $(document).ready(() => {
    $('#next').click(() => {
      //var url = 'localhost:5000/alldata';
      //var url = 'https://api.github.com/users/topjavatutorial/repos';
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/alldata',
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: (data) => {

          $.each(data, function (i) {

          });

          data[i]
          console.log(i);
          len = data.length;
          if (i < (len - 1)) {
            i++;
            var station_loop = '';
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data[i].Station));

            station_loop += '<li>ID: ' + JSON.stringify(data[i].ID) + '</li>' +
              '<li>Station: ' + JSON.stringify(data[i].Station) + '</li>' +
              '<li>Address: ' + JSON.stringify(data[i].Address) + '</li>' +
              '<li>Sales: ' + JSON.stringify(data[i].Monthly_CStore_Sales) + '</li>' +
              '<li>Operator: ' + JSON.stringify(data[i].Operator) + '</li>' +
              '<li>Top SKU: ' + JSON.stringify(data[i].Top_SKU) + '</li>' +
              '</<li>' + '<br/>';



            $('#storesNav').html(station_loop);
          }
        }
      })
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="previous">
      <<<<</button> <button type="button" id="next">>>>>
    </button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="storesNav"></div>
```